# Difference between IDE "Visual MASM" and "Easy Code"?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I'm new to the Assembly Language.

I was trying to build a sample assembler code (masm32), then I realize that:

- when using `Visual MASM`, the output is an .exe file with a size of
  **2,5 KB**.
- with the same code but with `Easy IDE Code` the size of the    .exe
  output file is **12 KB**.

**My questions:**

- For which reason this difference is due?
- Is there an IDE or a method that can minimize the size of output exe file better than those IDE?
- Can reducing the size of an .exe file affect performance of program?

Comment: Could be alignment, 4kb used to be a common exe alignment (0.5kb is more common now)

Comment: The size of your program doesn't matter so don't worry about it. You're using a computer with gigabytes of RAM and maybe a terabyte or more disk space.

Comment: What is a "ko"? Is that the same thing as a kilobyte? The larger file size is probably due to a run-time library being automatically linked into your executable; something like the Irvine32 library or a C runtime library.

Comment: 4 KB was a common alignment because Windows 98 loaded binaries slightly faster if they were aligned on page boundaries. That was the `/OPT:WIN98` flag for Microsoft's linker. This was the default in VC 6. On previous operating systems, and all later OSes (so basically anything *but* Windows 98), a 512-byte alignment is more sensible, because it saves space without introducing any performance penalty. That's the `/OPT:NOWIN98` linker flag in the Microsoft toolchain. If one of these IDEs are old enough, they may still be optimizing for Windows 98.

Comment: What's a bit odd about these numbers is that, according to [what I see online](http://www.easycode.cat/English/Tutorial/chapter1Materials/Chapter1Page4Text.html#compilingTheCode), Easy Code uses a *file packer* (UPX) to compress executable files in Release builds, so its output should actually be *smaller* than Visual MASM. Perhaps the difference is that one of these outputs includes debugging information? Are you creating debug builds, or not? What settings are you using in these IDEs? Without that information, this is an impossible question to answer definitively; all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your responses
 a big thank-you @CodyGray for your interaction
I don't know really the setting of those IDE
all what I was did it is linking those IDE with a folder named masm32 wich contain the MASM32 SDK file installation 

* When building code with Visual masm 3 files are generated : .exe file(2,50 KO) | .obj file(839 bytes ~ 1KO) | .vmp file

* When building code with Easy code a debug folder is generated with 5 files : .exe file(12KO) | .obj file(319KO) | .ilk file | .pdp file | .res file

Comment: Okay, so like I theorized, Easy Code is generating a debug build with symbols. These increase the size of your binary, but make debugging easier. Visual MASM isn't generating this debugging information. If you want to bring down the size of the EXE in Easy Code, then you'll need to figure out a way to switch the IDE over to making a "Release" build. I'm sure it's all covered in the documentation. [The tutorial I linked](http://www.easycode.cat/English/Tutorial/Chapter1.html) is probably a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of Visual MASM and I can confirm that the latest version of Visual MASM does not generate a debug build. That is why Visual MASM, at the moment, creates smaller EXE's than Easy Code at this time.

However, Visual MASM will have an option to enable its user-mode debugger. To enable the debugger, Visual MASM will generate the debug symbols for your assembly applications. This would add to the size of the target file. So, you will see a Release (non-debug), and a Debug (with symbols) assembly option.

Also, no EXE under Windows can be smaller than 1 KB. If you want smaller files, you would need to generate 16-bit COM files which you could do in Visual MASM as well. It also depends on which version of Windows you are running.